How to show all the data from my dask array in python?
I have a variable called "sum" with this information:
sum (time, lat, lon)float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 18, 3600), meta=np.ndarray> 
How do I show all the data that this variable has?

If you wouldn't mind putting your code into code blocks, this makes it more readable and easy to understand. That way we can also see what modules you are using.

@Alma you need to create a new Notebook or a new python file. In the new notebook make sure you do not have sum as your variable name.

You should not keep your variable name `sum`. 
sum is a built-in function name.
Please change your variable name.
Call .compute() when you want your result as a NumPy array.
your_variable.compute()

https://examples.dask.org/array.html

Try using the dir() function. It returns every property and methods of the objects.
dir(sum)

